# confirm validation With get alert value in textbox

Tags: javascript

I Want to confirm validation With get alert value  in textbox

if press ok, then get value ok in textbox. OR Press Cancel, then Get Value Cancel In textbox

```
function con2(message) 
{
    var answer = confirm("Do You Want To Save This Record");
    if (answer)
    {
        return true;
        //yes

    }
    return false;
// Cancel
}


<form action="" method="post">
Valid Value<input type="text" name="valid" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick=" return con2();" />
</form>
```

Comment: I want to help, but I can't understand what you are asking.  Can you rephrase the question/problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi as per my understanding what you asked is for filling the textbox with the some value.

You need to use a ID attribute and it will be easy to set the value.

for eg:

```
function myFunction() {
var x =confirm("YES OR NO") ;
if(x){
var text=document.getElementById("demo");
 text.value="OK";
 }
 else{
 var text=document.getElementById("demo")
 text.value="Cancel";
 }
}
<input type="text" id="demo" value=""/>
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">try it</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer for this question

```
 function con2(message) 
    {
        var answer = confirm("Do You Want To Save This Record");
        if (answer)
        {   
            document.getElementById('valid').value = "yes";
            return true;
        }
        document.getElementById('valid').value = "No";
        return false;
    }
<form action="" method="post">
Valid Value<input type="text" name="valid" value="" id="valid" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick=" return con2();" />
</form>
```